# Should Very Old Questions Remain Open on DBA.SE Even Though They Don't Have Answers

Tags: discussion

I think the title sums it up quite nicely:

**Should Very Old Questions Remain Open on DBA.SE Even Though They Don't Have Answers?**

A recent VtC on the following question raised some concern that the votes were not correctly cast and would hinder people answering the question:

[Fulltext indexes and issuers with server startup [on hold]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/34433/15356)

> **put on hold** as off-topic by Max Vernon, RDFozz, LowlyDBA, hot2use, Marco 37 mins ago
>
> This question appears to be off-topic. The users who voted to close gave this specific reason:
>
> - "**Tip of the iceberg** - the question or comments reveal an underlying issue that would need extensive investigation by a consultant or database vendor support team: issues like this do not fit the SE Q&A model well. For more information see this meta post." – Max Vernon, RDFozz, LowlyDBA, hot2use, Marco
>
> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

This question was initially migrated from stackoverflow.com and sent to our site for further scrutiny. It did not attract any attention (5 year, 2 months ago) and was closed for the above reason.

The original author did not register on DBA.SE and the question looked pretty much abandoned.

There was some [discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/44350466#44350466) about the question and the reason for the VtC and how the question could now no longer be answered because of the [on hold] status.

**Question:** Should such question be left open?

Comment: Related: [Should old questions that have no answers and are “too localized” or “too broad” be closed?](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1023)

Comment: Are you asking generally (as the title suggests) or about the specific example?

Comment: Both. And sorry, but my research didn't return any results so I thought it was a first (even though I couldn't believe my luck). No objections if we VtC as duplicate ;-)

Comment: ..and I upvoted Chris Tavers answer on that one.

Comment: Let's see what develops. People might want to discuss this specific question as well. (btw Cole is exactly right in his accepted answer).

Comment: Another one recently closed: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/107402/how-to-resolve-error-7311-returned-by-a-job-running-against-a-linked-server

Comment: @PaulWhite that [last comment](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/should-old-questions-that-have-no-answers-and-are-too-localized-or-too-broad/1025#comment3361_1025) on https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1025/171 is most important lol

Comment: @jcolebrand Agreed.

Answer (score 7):

Question age and/or lack of answers is not the criteria for closing; as you can see this question, as others like it, has been closed because it's impossible to answer as is and its author is not around to provide any additional information.

Answer (score 5):

I VtC'd that question since the OP states that they are looking at modifying the problem server by reducing the number of databases etc, and without that precise server around for verification, this question seems unanswerable to me.

It might have been closed as a dupe instead, but since it is about full text catalogs, I couldn't find any suitable target question.

Comment: Do you have a general opinion regarding **Closing Very Old Questions Without Answers**?

Comment: I agree with General Cole in his answer on the linked question.  If a question is old and answerable, I try to answer it.  If it's old and a pile-o-rubble, that cannot ever be helpful, I probably VtC it.

Comment: I had similar rationale on my VtC for this question. If the question is lacking details / response from OP that is key to making it answerable / useful to anyone, I usually VtC.